# How to use [OrchardFeature()] when creating modules with multiple features?

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules, orchardcms-1.10

I am working on Orchard CMS module which will contain multiple features,  I found that orchard has an attribute [OrchardFeature("Feature.Name")] which need to be applied to multiple features.

In my case I need Controller and Route to be part of the same feature, so I applied an attribute to both, but in that case, my controller returns 404.

**If I try to remove the attribute, it works fine and action of my controller can be found**.

```
[OrchardFeature("Yaplex.SEO.Robots")]
public class RobotsTxtController : Controller
{
    // GET: RobotsTxt
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("I am robots txt");
    }
}

[OrchardFeature("Yaplex.SEO.Robots")]
public class Routes : IRouteProvider {
    public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes() {
        return new[] {
            new RouteDescriptor {
                Priority = 10,
                Route = new Route(
                    "robots.txt", 
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "Yaplex.SEO"},
                        {"controller", "RobotsTxt"},
                        {"action", "Index"}
                    },
                    new RouteValueDictionary(),
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "Yaplex.SEO"}
                    },
                    new MvcRouteHandler())
            }
        };
    }

    public void GetRoutes(ICollection<RouteDescriptor> routes) {
        foreach (var routeDescriptor in GetRoutes())
            routes.Add(routeDescriptor);
    }
}
```

Is it something I doing wrong there?

Comment: Did you make sure to actually enable that feature from the Modules section from the dashboard?

Comment: Thanks, Sipke, you was right. I did not enable it. After enabling works for me. If you answer this question I will mark it as an answer (can't do it with comment)